# How to copy commit to another git repository

Tags: git

We have 2 repositories. One belong to company and one to client. Where client repository is empty now. How can I coppy stable(selected)  commits to client repo?

Comment: with git remote you may add distant repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your stable development is on a clearly-identified branch (often the name `master` is used for that), you can handle deployment to your client's site directly from you git client.

First, add the client's remote repository as a second remote:

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote add <alias> <url>
```

If it's empty the following will have no effect, but it's useful to see that the connection works (if no output, everything is OK):

```
git fetch <alias>
```

Now you can push your stable branch to that remote repository:

```
git push <alias> master
```

Answer (score 1):

Change remote to other repository, then fetch its changes. There you can see the commit and cherry-pick it. You can format patch as well

```
git --git-dir=../<some_other_repo>/.git \
format-patch -k -1 --stdout <commit SHA> | \
git am -3 -k
```

Answer (score -1):

I download whole project on on the state of specific commit
https://bitbucket.org/account_name/repository_name/get/commit_name.zip
copy allfiles to client repository and push to client remote from there